# How to create a Url without UrlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create a Url based in the Action/Controller name + route values.

I know that it is possible to use `UrlHelper.Action`, but I am running the method in an async way, so the `HttpContext.Current` will be always `null`.

Is there other for building a URL?

I've seen a few examples, but I need to know about the situation where I don't know the name of the domain (hostname or application_name), and it need to build the URL only based on Action + Controller + Route values.

As I haven't created anything yet I don't have any code to show.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the base of the URL before calling the async method (you have context at that point) and then fill the remaining values when you finished executing the method.

Comment: @Francisco-godenstein, unfortunatelly, it isn't an option to me... it would fix my problem, but are 2 different contexts (controller/class)

Comment: Could you please give me more information about it? based on your description my solution seems to be fine.

Comment: I have a class that create an object, and I receive as parameter the Action name, Controller name and the route values. My controller access a BusinessLayer that invokes a async method that fires an object to my client via SignalR. This object will have the link that was composed by the information of those parameters. I could fix it by doing what you said, but, as I only can receive the name of the action, controller plus the routevalues, I have no other option.

Comment: You can't change the signature of that method? why can't you add a hostname or a URL placeholder as parameter to that method? can you send the hostname or a link placeholder to the class that contains that method?

Comment: I can't. I wasn't well projected.Any other tip?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run through RouteTable.Routes. Find the most suitable and form the url.
Something like this

```
foreach (var rr in RouteTable.Routes){
  var r=(Route)rr;
  if (r.Defaults["controller"].ToString()=="myController" && ...){
    return r.Url+"?"+routeValue1.Key+"="+routeValue1.Value ...
```

It's just an idea. The real code must be safer to avoid null references and more complicated to check route constrains, replace patterns and etc.